# How to pass array of IEnumerable<int> from one view to another in ASP.NET MVC correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In the code below I have created an index view that enables users to check records that they want to update. When clicking on the submit button, they are supposed to be redirected to a webpage, and some code needs to be executed to update these records.

The following is the code that I have implemented:

The view:

```
@model IEnumerable<BulkDelete.Models.Employee>

@{int[] employeesToUpdate;}
    <div style="font-family:Arial">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateMultiple", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Checkbox<br /></td>

                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="employeesToUpdate" id="employeesToUpdate" value="@item.ID" />
                            </td>
                            <td>@item.Name</td>
                            <td>@item.Gender</td>
                            <td>@item.Email</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <input type="submit"  value="update selected employees" />
        }
    </div>
```

The controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BulkDelete.Models;

namespace BulkDelete.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        SampleDBContext db = new SampleDBContext();
        public  System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState Session { get; }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Employees.ToList()) ;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateMultiple(IEnumerable<int> employeesToUpdate)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UpdateMultipleRecords");
        }
        
        //[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateMultipleRecords()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> employeesToUpdate = (IEnumerable<int>)TempData["employeesToUpdate"];
            var listemployee = db.Employees.Where(x => employeesToUpdate.Contains(x.ID));

            foreach (var item in listemployee)
            {
                int itemid = item.ID;

                Employee e = db.Employees.Find(itemid);
                e.Email = "hello.";
                // e = db.Employees.Find(item);
                db.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the same error over and over:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>
> Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
> Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Your form post method expects this signature, you also seem to be depending on TempData in the RedirectToAction, so you need to set the TempData in your post method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateMultiple(IEnumerable<int> employeesToUpdate)
    {
        //Set the TempData
        TempData["employeesToUpdate"] = employeesToUpdate;
        return RedirectToAction("UpdateMultipleRecords");
    }
```

In your view, you need to modify the name attribute on your checkbox elements like so, since it is an `IEnumerable` the name needs to be indexed, also, currently you are using the same `id` on all your checkboxes, `id` should be unique to each element, so you can use the `iter` variable to append to the `id` of the checkboxes:

```
@{int[] employeesToUpdate;} @*This doesn't look like it's necessary*@
@{int iter = 0;} @*Declare an iterator variable*@
```

.......

```
@for (var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
        <td>
           @*index the controller parameter's IEnumerable*@
           <input type="checkbox" name="employeesToUpdate[@iter]" id="employeesToUpdate_@iter" value="@item.ID" /> 
        </td>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Gender</td>
        <td>@item.Email</td>
   </tr>
   iter++;
 }
```